# How do I get a username from a message ID in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to get the author of a message that has been reacted to, but I can't find anything in the discord.py API reference that allows me to find a the author off of just payload, so I figured the closest thing would be to find them off the message itself.

````
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if str(payload.emoji)=='':
        with app.app_context():
            blasted_user: str = # ??
            blasting_user: str = payload.member
            log: str = datetime.now().strftime("%D:%H:%M:%S")
            message_id: int = payload.message_id
            #The site isn't letting me post this unless I split message into 2 lines
            m1 = await client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message: str = await m1.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            db.session.add(data(blasted_user, blasting_user, message, log, message_id))
            db.session.commit()```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is good, since you now have a message object with:

```py
message_id: int = payload.message_id
m1 = await client.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
message = await m1.fetch_message(message_id)
```

to get the message author:

```py
author = message.author
```

Comment: Ah it would seem I am a little dense, thanks man I was pulling my hair over that ToT